# Relation between determinant of  two matrices

Tags: matrices, determinant

$A$ is a matrix with $1$ along diagonal and arbitrary unequal numbers less than $1$ on its non-diagonal. Let $B$ is a matrix with same $1$ along diagonal but having maximum non-diagonal element of $A$ as its non-diagonal element. What would be the relation between $\det (A)$ and $\det(B)$?  Suppose $A$ and $B$ are correlation matrices. Does increasing the off-diagonal entries i.e. correlation coefficient decreases determinant?

Comment: What type of relation are you looking for?

Comment: Like $det(A)$ greater or smaller than $det (B)$

Comment: It could be greater, smaller or the same.

Comment: At what conditions it will greater or smaller. It is noted that all elements are positive.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that if $A = \frac{1}{10}\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 10 \ 2 \ 3 \\ 4 \ 10 \ 5 \\ 6 \ 7 \ 10 \end{array}\right)$ then $B = \frac{1}{10}\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 10 \ 7 \ 7 \\ 7 \ 10 \ 7 \\ 7 \ 7 \ 10 \end{array}\right)$?

Comment: Do the non-diagonal elements of $A$ need to be _all_ different?

Comment: You are right except that non diagonal element should be less than 1. like 0.2,0.4 etc.

Comment: All non-diagonal elements of $A$ are different.

Comment: Yes... matrix A and B in example are correct

Comment: It is true that the off-diagonal are small. I tried Gershgorin's circle theorem. But could not find a concrete proof. I have some simulation results that show $det(B)\leq det (A)$ but could not prove mathematically.

Comment: If $B$ is $n \times n$ with diagonal elements 1 and  off-diagonal elements $b$, then 
$\det(B) = ((n-1)b + 1)(1-b)^{n-1}$.  A couple of interesting examples for $A$: 
$\det \pmatrix{1 & b & b\cr b & 1 & 0\cr b & 0 & 1\cr} = 1 - 2 b^2$, $\det \pmatrix{1 & b & 0 & b\cr b & 1 & b & 0\cr 0 & b & 1 & b\cr b & 0 & b & 1\cr} = 1 - 4 b^2$.

Comment: You might note that $\frac{\partial}{\partial a_{ij}} \det(A)$ does not depend on $a_{ij}$, so the minimum of $\det(A)$ subject to all $a_{ij} \in [0, b]$ will occur at a point where each $a_{ij} \in \{0, b\}$.  Now in this case $\det(A) = 1 - k b^2 + O(b^3)$ where $k$ is the number of pairs $i,j$ with 
$a_{i,j} = a_{j,i} = b$.  So for $b$ sufficiently small (depending on $n$), you do have $\det(B) \le \det(A)$.

Comment: Thanks. you have clearly understood my problem. But I need a proof, like in which conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enumerate the matrices $n \times n$ matrices $A_m$ with diagonal elements 1 and off-diagonal elements either $b$ or $0$, with at least one $0$ (there are $2^{n^2-n} - 1$ such matrices, but we can use symmetry to make the calculations somewhat more tractable).  For each $m$, $\det(A_m) = 1 - k b^2 + O(b^3)$  where $k$ is the number of pairs $(i,j)$ such that
$(A_m)_{ij} = (A_m)_{ji} = b$, while $\det(B) = 1 - \frac{n^2-n}{2} b^2 + O(b^3)$.  Thus $\det(A_m) \ge \det(B)$ for $0 \le b \le b_m$ where $ b_m > 0$. Then any $A$ with
diagonal elements 1 and off-diagonal elements in $[0,b]$ will have $\det(A) \ge \det(B)$ 
as long as $0 \le b \le \min_m b_m$.  I don't know if there's a closed-form formula for  $\epsilon(n) = \min_m b_m$.  The first few values, obtained by exhaustive enumeration, are $\epsilon(2) = \infty$, $\epsilon(3) = 1/2$, $\epsilon(4) = (4 - \sqrt{10})/3$, $\epsilon(5) = -3/4\,\cos \left( 1/3\,\arctan \left( 4/7\,\sqrt {2} \right)  \right) 
+5/4-3/4\,\sqrt {3}\sin \left( 1/3\,\arctan \left( 4/7\,\sqrt {2}
 \right)  \right)$.    This last is the least positive root of $-2+12 b-15 b^2+4 b^3$, corresponding to $A_m = \left[ \begin {array}{ccccc} 1&b&b&b&b\\ b&1&b&b&0\\ b&b&1&0&b\\ b&b&0&1&b
\\ b&0&b&b&1\end {array} \right]$

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: Excellent answer!!!